Display 2 arrows on same bar separately
I have pinescript v5 code that may display 2 arrows on the same bar on certain occasions. How do I make the arrows appear separately on the same bar? Currently, they overlap each other and I can only see one bar.
plotshape(series=X_downwards, title="X_downwards", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, 
          color=color.aqua, size=size.small)
          
plotshape(series=Y_downwards, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, style=shape.arrowup, 
          title="Y_downwards", size=size.small) 

  


Add the arrows as text to the plots. Use U+200E (Decimal 8206) as a non-printing space after the last "\n".
See article.
plotshape(series=X_downwards, title="X_downwards", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.white, size=size.small, textcolor = color.aqua, text="↑")
          
plotshape(series=Y_downwards, title="Y_downwards", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.white,  size=size.small, textcolor = color.red, text="‎\n↑") 

